# facing irritating add pop-ups

Tags: android-versions

I am using micromax Yureca handset and installed Android 4.4.

I don't want to reset my device, so can someone please tell me what is this all and what is `smartApp`, ads coming on behalf of it, but can't find it as a installed app ?

Comment: *Yureca* -> Yureka, *add* -> ad. Please [edit].

Comment: On a quick note, [YuForums](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/) is a community dedicated for anything related to Yureka device . You can always post your issue there (besides here) and if you haven't done so, since having all Yureka users there provides better chances to deal with  the issue. About the ads, you can look for solutions here on this website by using Search option. [Here](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/searching) is a useful guide for advanced searching. You can also Google "how to block ads on unrooted device"?

Comment: About the *smartApp*, you said you can't find it as an installed app. So, do you see it inside the ads  or you have an icon in the launcher?